# Invocation of release_task() function?

Tags: process, linux-kernel, wait

In `Linux kernel`, the `process descriptor` of a process is removed from the system by invoking the `release_task()` function, after the process has terminated.

I believe, the `wait()` system call issued by the parent process on the child process invokes the `release_task()` function when the child process terminates.

Suppose the parent process does not issue a `wait()` system call explicitly, how is `release_task()` function invoked and the process descriptor of the child process deallocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the parent process does not `wait(2)` for a child process, the child becomes a `zombie`. As long as the parent lives, **the child cannot be reaped**. When the parent dies, all his un-waited children are adopted by `init`. One of the jobs of `init` is to periodically wait for children (thereby freeing associated resources)

Comment: Thanks. I understood. Does the wait() system call invoke the release_task() function?

Answer (score 0):

The  **release_task( )**  function detaches the last data structures from the descriptor of a zombie process; it is applied on a zombie process in two possible ways: by the  **do_exit( )**  function if the parent is not interested in receiving signals from the child, or by the  **wait4( )**  or  **waitpid( )**  system calls after a signal has been sent to the parent. In the latter case, the function also will reclaim the memory used by the process descriptor, while in the former case the memory reclaiming will be done by the scheduler because the **do_exit()** calls **schedule ()** in its last step.

For more information,you can refer to the book - *Understanding The Linux Kernel:I/O Ports And Process Management*.